# beamer footnote numbers in overprint

Tags: beamer, footnotes, overlays

I have a series of text + images that I want to appear on the same slide.
Both the text and image have some reference to be quoted for which I am using footnotes (this is done throughout the presentation).

I am facing 2 issues:

1. When I use `\footnote{}` within the `overprint`, the footnote
   numbers get changed to letters. However, I would want the footnote to continue the number from the previous slide's footnote.
2. On all slides, the same footnote letters are shown. I want the footnote numbers to be incremented.

Here is my attempt.
How can I resolve both the issues?

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test Frame}
\begin{overprint}

\onslide<1>
\vspace*{1.5cm}
First line~\footnote{footnote 1-slide 1}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{jinglebells}\\
Jingle bells~\footnote{footnote 2-slide 1}

\onslide<2>
\vspace*{1.5cm}
Second line~\footnote{footnote 1-slide 2}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{holiday}\\
Holiday picture~\footnote{footnote 2- slide 2}


\end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the dirty hack I have now is to use `[noframenumbering]` option and create new frames for each expected overprint. i am looking at a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy workaround.

---

### First option

Footnotes inside an `overprint` are tratead as `minipage`'s footnotes.

What you can do is

1. transform footnote marks in numeric ones through the command

   ```
   \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
   ```
2. Insert this line at the beginning of each `\onslide`

   ```
   \setcounter{mpfootnote}{\value{footnote}}
   ```

   and this one at its end

   ```
   \setcounter{footnote}{\value{mpfootnote}}
   ```

   to count these footnotes as normal ones.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx} %remove this line in your document
\documentclass{beamer}

\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test Frame}
\begin{overprint}

\onslide<1>
\setcounter{mpfootnote}{\value{footnote}}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
First line~\footnote{footnote 1-slide 1}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{jinglebells}\\
Jingle bells~\footnote{footnote 2-slide 1}
\setcounter{footnote}{\value{mpfootnote}}

\onslide<2>
\setcounter{mpfootnote}{\value{footnote}}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
Second line~\footnote{footnote 1-slide 2}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{holiday}\\
Holiday picture~\footnote{footnote 2- slide 2}
\setcounter{footnote}{\value{mpfootnote}}

\end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

### Second option

Declare footnotes at frame-level using the optional argument `frame`:

```
\footnote[frame]{...}
```

MWE

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx} %remove this line in your document
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test Frame}
\begin{overprint}

\onslide<1>
\vspace*{1.5cm}
First line~\footnote[frame]{footnote 1-slide 1}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{jinglebells}\\
Jingle bells~\footnote[frame]{footnote 2-slide 1}

\onslide<2>
\vspace*{1.5cm}
Second line~\footnote[frame]{footnote 1-slide 2}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{holiday}\\
Holiday picture~\footnote[frame]{footnote 2- slide 2}

\end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output in this case, however, shows all footnotes in all slides....

[image]

---

### Third option

Add also the slide number to the footnote.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx} %remove this line in your document
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test Frame}
\begin{overprint}

\onslide<1>
\vspace*{1.5cm}
First line~\footnote<1>[frame]{footnote 1-slide 1}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{jinglebells}\\
Jingle bells~\footnote<1>[frame]{footnote 2-slide 1}

\onslide<2>
\vspace*{1.5cm}
Second line~\footnote<2>[frame]{footnote 1-slide 2}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{holiday}\\
Holiday picture~\footnote<2>[frame]{footnote 2- slide 2}

\end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the output of the second slide shows a blank space where the footnotes of the first slide are.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! +1 for "Footnotes inside an overprint are tratead as minipage's footnotes". I did not know how it works. Your second and third option are not that complicated. I can use that.

Comment: @okkhoy Happy it helped!